# How can I map a Flow where a property of an object is changing, not the object itself?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am mapping a flow of a certain class and transforming that Flow to a StateFlow and using it in DataBinding. My problem is that the classe's properties are not immutable and in case there is a modification in one of them the mapping is not recomputing, because not the object itself changed.
Does anyone have any idea how can I emit a new value in case the property changed?

Comment: It's probably best to _make_ the class's properties immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Louis says in the comments, it would be better to have immutable properties, and push a new instance of the *state* you want to share. That's how `StateFlow` operates, using equality to check for actual changes, and suppressing updates that don't appear to change anything (see the *Strong equality-based conflation* bit [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/)).

But it's also how a lot of other things work, e.g. [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) compares a new set of data with the previous set, to see what's changed and how to tell the adapter exactly what it needs to update. If you're using a mutable list, and passing the same instance as new data, then unless the adapter has made its own copy then the *"new list"* is the same as the *"old list"*, and there are no detectable changes. By changing the underlying data, instead of providing new copies of it, you introduce bugs and other weird behaviour.

---

Anyhow, if you really can't do that, maybe you could use `SharedFlow` with a `repeat` of *1* instead. That basically behaves like `LiveData`, pushing an update with every new value, whereas `StateFlow` behaves more like a `distinctUntilChanged` `LiveData`. The other difference is that a `StateFlow` *requires* an initial value, whereas `SharedFlow` doesn't - so you might need to account for that in your code, there might not be a value in the flow when you first `collect` it.

[Quick demo:](https://pl.kotl.in/pPt1q8NSR)

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        
        val someFlow = flow {
            // the consumer of this flow is gonna get this same list object over and over
            val myList = mutableListOf<Int>()
            (1..5).forEach { number ->
                delay(100)
                myList.add(number)
                emit(myList)
            }
        }
        
        val scope = CoroutineScope(currentCoroutineContext())
        // remember normal flows run independently each time they're consumed,
        // so these two are getting their own source flow instances with separate lists
        val stateFlow = someFlow.stateIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, initialValue = emptyList())
        val sharedFlow = someFlow.shareIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, replay = 1)
        
        launch { stateFlow.collect { println("StateFlow: $it") } }
        launch { sharedFlow.collect { println("SharedFlow: $it") } }
        launch { 
            delay(450)
            sharedFlow.collect { println("Some latecomer: $it") }
        }
        
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            scope.cancel("Shared and StateFlows keep running forever unless their scope finishes")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// StateFlow pushes its initial value (since the flow delays before it emits anything)
StateFlow: []
// StateFlow gets its first item, the list. Since it gets the same list object
// every time after that, it's comparing the same object to itself, and never updates again
StateFlow: [1]

// Shared flow emits nothing until the upstream flow emits something
SharedFlow: [1]
// then every time the list is re-emitted, the SharedFlow pushes it - it doesn't care
SharedFlow: [1, 2]
SharedFlow: [1, 2, 3]
SharedFlow: [1, 2, 3, 4]

// Once the other collector shows up, because repeat=1, it gets the last (1) items
// shared by the SharedFlow - so it sees the list the other collector just got
Some latecomer: [1, 2, 3, 4]
SharedFlow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Some latecomer: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```